# Serialization bugs in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, soap-serialization

I'm reading up on serialization, and have so far been messing with BinaryFormatter and SoapFormatter. So far, so good - and everything have both Serialized and Deserialized perfectly.

However, when I try the code below, I would expect my datafile to NOT contains the info for Name - and it does. Why would it contain that, when I specify SoapIgnore on the field?

I also tried with `SoapAttribute("SomeAttribute")` on the Age-field, and that didn't make any difference either. The framework version is set to 2.0, but the same thing happens in 3.5 and 4.0.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.Age = 42;
        p.Name = "Mr Smith";

        SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\test\data.txt", FileMode.Create);

        formatter.Serialize(fs, p);
    }
}

[Serializable]
class Person
{
    public int Age;
    [SoapIgnore]
    public string Name;
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Use [`[NonSerialized]`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx) instead of `[SoapIgnore]`

Furthermore, this is an older (and aging) API. Not directly wrong but be sure to read up on [XmlSerialization](http://blog.kowalczyk.info/article/Serialization-in-C.html) and [ProtoBuf](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf/) as well.

And be careful not to mix the API's up. Serialization is part of SOAP communication but not the same. SoapAttribute is not involved in bare Serialization.

Comment: Nope. Not correct.

[NonSerialized] is for the BinaryFormatter.
[SoapIgnore] is for the SoapFormatter.
[XmlIgnore] is for the XmlSerializer.

Comment: @Peter: Are you sure? From MSDN: When using the BinaryFormatter or SoapFormatter classes to serialize an object, use the NonSerializedAttribute attribute ...., http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx

Comment: @Peter: According to the docs
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.soapattributes.soapignore.aspx [SoapIgnore] is for the XMLSerializer, not the SoapFormatter

Comment: Actually, I'd stay away from the XML Serializer as well, unless you require control over the exact format of the XML. It's in the process of being dropped, along with ASMX web services.

Comment: So how would I go about serializing an object either through BinaryFormatter, SoapFormatter or XmlSerializer, where I have control over which fields is serialized? The only way seems to be implemented ISerializable - and that might be a TAD overkill.

Comment: OK @John, thanks for the tip. Do you have a link for the ASMX state of affairs?

Comment: I found a solution - I answered it below. It seems that the SoapFormatter uses NonSerialized just like the BinaryFormatter does.

Comment: And it seems that the MS Press book I'm reading is wrong, in listing SoapIgnore and SoapAttribute alongside SoapFormatters.

Comment: @Henk: no single link, unfortunately. The strongest hint is in Ed Pinto's reply to https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/362727/xsd-exe-incorrect-class-generated-for-abstract-type-with-derived-types. That and the fact that ASMX web services are replaced by WCF, and XML Serialization has only limited applicability to WCF.

Answer (score 1):

Because serialization and SOAP aren't the same. You have `Name` marked as public, so the serializer will serialize/deserialize it. If you want it not to appear in a serialization you should change its protection level to protected.

Comment: This isn't only way to ignore some fields during serialization.

Comment: There is a SoapFormatter which is designed to serialized data. I'm not talking about a webservice soap envelope.

The MSDN it self states the following about SoapFormatters:

"Serializes and deserializes an object, or an entire graph of connected objects, in SOAP format."

Comment: @Bart, @Peter Olsen - I read a little more into your question and some of the responses, and my "answer" isn't complete or accurate. I was tempted to delete it, but that would deprive potential downvoters of a clear and present opportunity.

Answer (score 1):

From the [docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.soapattributes.soapignore.aspx) it states that the `[SoapIgnore]` attribute tells the `XMLSerializer` not to serialize this property, and it doesn't mention the `SoapFormatter` so I assume it doesn't apply to it, even though the name suggests it does

Comment: If I use an XmlSerializer, and use the [SoapIgnore] attribute, it serializes the field. If I change the attribute to [XmlIgnore] it correctly ignores the field.

It just makes no sense, that there is no way to tell the serializer, that a given public field shouldn't be serialized. Lets say that I have string firstname, lastname, fullname, and fullname is in the ctor set to firstname +" "+ lastname. Why would I then want to serialize fullname? But I need fullname to be public.

Comment: [NonSerialized] seems to make the SoapFormatter ignore the field.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works. It seems that the SoapFormatter uses the same attributes as the BinaryFormatter does - the [NonSerialized] attribute. This however goes against what the MS Press book I'm reading states. It lists SoapIgnore, SoapAttribute and others as attributes that works with the SoapFormatter when serializing data.

This code creates two files, none of them having the Name-field.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Soap;
using System.IO;
using System.Xml.Serialization;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Person p = new Person();
        p.Age = 42;
        p.Name = "Mr Smith";

        FormatSoap(p);
        FormatXml(p);
    }

    private static void FormatXml(Person p)
    {
        XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Person));
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\test\xmldata.txt", FileMode.Create);

        serializer.Serialize(fs, p);
    }

    private static void FormatSoap(Person p)
    {
        SoapFormatter formatter = new SoapFormatter();
        FileStream fs = new FileStream(@"c:\test\soapdata.txt", FileMode.Create);

        formatter.Serialize(fs, p);
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class Person
{
    public int Age;
    [XmlIgnore]
    [NonSerialized]
    public string Name;
}
```

Comment: Of course this doesn't mean I can alter how I want the resulting soapenvelope to be created - setting some values to soap-attributes and renaming other fields.

Comment: @Peter: which book, and when was it published?

Comment: @John: It's the Self Paced Training Kit for the 70-536 exam (.Net Application Development Foundation). It's even the second edition from 2009.

Comment: @Peter: which version of .NET is the exam for?

Comment: @Peter: BTW, just read the code and have to downvote you for not using `using` blocks around the FileStream's.

Comment: @John hehe, the code isn't productioncode or anything - it was just to make a simple example. The exam is for 2.0.

Comment: The way the code works directly goes against what the MS Press book says? Shocking...

Comment: @Peter: non-production, example code is copied by those who don't know what production code looks like, and is actually used. Fix it and I'll remove the -1.

Comment: @John: should all SO answers be copy-pate ready or focus on the problem as clear as possible?

Comment: @Henk: I compromise on that by downvoting lack of `using` blocks, missing any locking, and use of `new XmlTextReader()/XmlTextWriter()`These are cases that I've seen used in real code; when asked, the devs have said, "but I got it from an example".

Comment: @Henk: also, anyone who says, "use WSE".

Comment: @John, uhhh WSE in this context = ??

Comment: @Henk: i was enumerating my reasons for auto downvotes. WSE is a very obsolete web service technology replaced by WCF

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this question: [Applying SoapIgnore attribute doesn't take any effect to serialization result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2283482/applying-soapignore-attribute-doesnt-take-any-effect-to-serialization-result/2285142#2285142)

Comment: The answer to that question states, that the SoapIgnore attribute is only for webservices. My question origins from reading the MS Press book for 70-536, where it clearly states that SoapIgnore and SoapAttribute works in union with SoapFormatter for serializing objects.

Comment: Right, but those books are notorious for having mistakes in them. Have you checked the book corrections page to see if it's listed? http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en/us/training/format-books-support.aspx#tab2